# Disable sudo prompt without disabling the need for sudo password

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

This is quite tricky I guess, or at least not desired very often.

What I am **not after** is:

Disabling password with

```
 user    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:    ALL
```

Or a similar trick.

I know how to read sudo password from `stdin`, and this is working fine
but you still get the prompt:

```
$ echo $PW | sudo -S whoami
[sudo] password for oz123: root
```

The man page shows I can use `-p`.

```
$ echo $PW | sudo -S -p "foo " whoami
foo root

$ echo $PW | sudo -S -p " " whoami
 root
```

A single space works.

Passing an empty string does not seem to work ...

```
$ echo $PW | sudo -S -p "" whoami
[sudo] password for oz123: root
```

So the question is:

How do you define an empty string as a valid value for `-p`?

#### update - sudo version

```
$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.21p2
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.21p2
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.21p2
```

(on ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: I wonder if a null `\0` is allowed?

Comment: Nope, `$ echo $PW | sudo -S -p '\0' whoami` gives
`\0root`

Comment: I have sudo 1.8.22 and can specify an empty string with -p  (openSUSE 15.0). what version are you using?

Comment: If you are also using `-S` you can redirect the prompt with ` 2>/dev/null` (along with any error messages).

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want the prompt to not be visible?

Comment: The problem is aesthetic. I have a script which runs on a remote machine, and I don't want to see the prompt in the logs. I can live with the solution of redirecting stderr to /dev/null

Comment: Try this : `echo $PW | sudo -S -p $'\0' whoami`

Comment: Doen't work in ubuntu 18.04, works in gentoo though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with newer versions of sudo this problem is solved:

On my gentoo laptop:

```
$ sudo -k
$ echo "$PW" | sudo -S -p "" whoami
root

$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.25p1
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.25p1
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.25p1
```

On older Ubuntu machines you can simply redirect the prompt to `/dev/null`:

```
sudo -S 2>/dev/null whoami
```